# Ruby on Rails: Get mediaplayer information (iTunes, TRAKTOR, Cog; current song + playlist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, itunes, playlist

I want to write a small web app which does this things:

- deliver a web page to display the current song and some meta data
- provide a web api which can be queried for the next song to allow the page to update without page load

No big deal, the only part I can't estimate is if it's possible to access the current song of [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/), [TRAKTOR](http://www.native-instruments.com/#/en/products/dj/traktor-pro/) and if possible [Cog](http://cogx.org/) from a ruby on rails application.

It would be especially nice if I can access the playlist, too to display the following song, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use applescript via the command-line. I don't have Traktor Pro or Coq, but you can look at what objects are available via the AppleScript Dictionary viewer in OS X's Script Editor. For iTunes, the command would be:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to get name of current track'
osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to get name of every track of current playlist'
```

You would execute the command from your rails app (which would need to be running as your user account) like this:

```
def show
    @current_track = `osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to get name of current track'`
end
```

...

```
<h1>The current track is: <%= @current_track -%></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks this should work. Cog provides AppleScript functions, as well as iTunes. TRAKTOR does not provide any API so I have to miss out on this programm.

Comment: There's still a way to applescript applications that don't support it using the System Events framework. Here is a pointer: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html

Comment: You should leave a link to video of this in action when it goes to "production".

Answer (score 1):

I've never even heard of the other two players you are mentioning, but with iTunes this is definitely possible. Look at this project for example: http://code.google.com/p/itunes-rails/

There should be a scripting bridge that can communicate with iTunes. Not sure about the other players, though.

Comment: TRAKTOR is a DJ software, Coq a simple music player like winamp. I am taking a look at itunes-rails.

Answer (score 0):

Traktor you can only access the names via two ways:

- capturing data from its ice cast broadcast
- using a work around by tricking it into thinking a demon device is connected, capturing the MIDI output data and converting via this JavaScript

https://github.com/Sonnenstrahl/traktor-now-playing