# MonoMac - how can I execute apple script

Tags: objective-c, mono, applescript, monomac, monobjc

I am trying to create a simple app with MonoMac and need to execute apple script to access playlist information from different media players (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617609/ruby-on-rails-get-mediaplayer-information-itunes-traktor-cog-current-song)).

I decided to give MonoMac a try because I am very familiar with C# and .net development and there is a nice Websocket implementation.

Unfortunately there seems to be no working wrapper for NSAppleScript. I tried [Frederic Forjans implementation](http://forjan.fr/) and tried to use [monobjc](http://api.monobjc.net/html/T_Monobjc_Cocoa_NSAppleScript.htm).

Frederics wrapper class does not even compile when I use his code I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MonoMac, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MonoMac, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

when creating a new `NSString` instance. However `new NSDictionary();` which is located in the same assembly works fine.

When using monobjc I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was 
thrown by the type initializer for Monobjc.ObjectiveCRuntime ---> 
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: monobjc_install_bridge
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Monobjc.NativeMethods:InstallBridge ()
  at Monobjc.ObjectiveCRuntime..cctor () [0x00000] in :0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at CocoaApplication1.Program.Main () [0x00000] in :0
```

Can anyone suggest a simple and working way to execute apple scripts in a mono environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the Monobjc assemblies directly without running them with the Monobjc runtime binary. Whether you want to build a Cocoa based or console application, [there are tutorials](http://www.monobjc.net/index.php?page=tutorials) for that on the Monobjc's website to help you getting started.

The easiest way to achieve inter-application communication is to use the ScriptingBridge framework. Many applications provide scripting definitions that can be then used in an object-oriented way: [take a look at this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more details.

Note that the scripting bridge will only works with scripting enabled applications (like iTunes, iCal, iMovie, Finder, etc).

Monobjc supports the ScriptingBridge framework; there are even two sample applications ([SBSetFinderComment](http://www.monobjc.net/index.php?page=sbsetfindercomment) and [ScriptingBridgeiCal](http://www.monobjc.net/index.php?page=scriptingbridgeical)) that show how to integrate it.

Comment: How can I check if an application is scripting enabled? Check the function browser in apples script editor?

Comment: There are two ways: (1) in the Apple Script Editor, choose File > Open Dictionary; the appplication should be listed or (2) in a Terminal prompt, type "sdef /Applications/<YourApp>.app"; if there is an error, then the application is not scriptable.

Answer (score 1):

If possible try using Monobjc. Monobjc provides a very straightforward way of executing custom AppleScript.

The following code snippet shows the main steps:

```
string script = ". . . . . . . . . ."; // some applescript text
NSDictionary error = null;
NSAppleScript scr = new NSAppleScript(script);
NSAppleEventDescriptor result = scr.ExecuteAndReturnError(out error);
string retval = result.StringValue;
```

I have written a [blog post](http://techunfold.com/?p=47) explaining the same. There's also a sample Monobjc project provided.

Comment: This would be really nice, I will try this as soon as I manage to get some free time :)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to execute AppleScript from a WinForms Mono project and ended up building my own little AppleScript execution library called AppleScript Slim.  !00% of the code came from the Mono Develop project.

AppleScript Slim: https://applescriptslim.codeplex.com/